# switching between one and two displays in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

Most of the time I work Visual Studio with two monitors.
I setup my Visual Studio to sit nicely across both monitors with code on the one side and property windows etc. on the other.

However, occasionally I need to remove into my work station from home where I only have one monitor.
What ends up happening is I have to re-setup my entire workspace to be used on one monitor, and when I get back to my work station I have to undo this again to get to my optimal 2 monitor environment.

Is there a way to save some set layouts in Visual Studio so I could quickly switch back and forward?
Example: One Monitor Layout versus Two Monito Layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stumbled upon this which really helped:

[link text](http://www.invisible-city.com/sharon/2008/06/workstation-hack-visual-studio-on-2.html)

The actual solution seems to throw an error for me, but one of the comments suggests you use your "full screen" view to do it.

So I setup my screen the way I like it.
Then I press "shift+alt+enter" which turns on full screen mode. 
I then setup my environment for "One Screen mode: (ironic, I know)
Visual Studio now remembers my full screen setup.

So now when I remote in I can just press "shift+alt+enter" and I'm in one screen mode.
Hopefully this post will help someone else, otherwise I would be interested to hear other solutions.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 with Windows 7